Problem with equivalence between local lorentz gauge field transformation law and lorentz transformation law of the spin connection
Defining spin connection, the transformation law under lorentz transformations is
$\omega_{\mu}{}^{a'}{}_{b'}=\Lambda^{a'}_{a}\Lambda^{b}_{b'}\omega_{\mu}{}^{a}{}_{b}+\Lambda^{a'}_{a}(\partial_{\mu}\Lambda)^{a}_{b'}$.
On the other side, define the spinorial representation of Lorentz group $S(\Lambda)=\exp(\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{ab}S_{ab})$ acting on a spinor $\psi'=S\psi$, given the covariant derivative of spinors $\nabla_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}+\frac{1}{2}\omega_{\mu}{}^{ab}S_{ab}$, the transformation law of the gauge field 1-form $\omega_{\mu}$ is
$\omega_{\mu}{}^{a'b'}S_{a'b'}=\omega_{\mu}{}^{ab}S(\Lambda)S_{ab}S^{-1}(\Lambda)-\partial_{\mu}(S) S^{-1}$
I need help relating those two. The first term is easier because it is the adjoint representation of the group acting on the algebra. But i'm struggling with the relation of the derivative term. I have tried computing Duhamel's formula for objects like $\frac{d}{dt}e^{Z(t)}$ but i did not find it useful.

In case its helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/406822/a-question-on-the-transformation-law-of-the-spin-connection
